unable to connect to ports exposed in qemu-arm
qemu-system-arm 
-cpu arm1176 
-m 256 
-net nic 
-nic user,hostfwd=tcp::${SSH_PORT}-:22 
-nic user,hostfwd=tcp::${EXTRA_PORT}-:4444 
-kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie 
-M versatilepb 
-no-reboot 
-serial stdio 
-append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw console=ttyAMA0" 
-nographic -monitor /dev/null 
-hda ./raspbian-stretch.img
this is my qemu setup command
whenever i run gdbserver or nc.traditional command from port 4444 and connect it via 6987 in my host i am getting slirp: failed to send packet, ret: -1
i couldnt really find any useful page fixing this problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
